# HLSL odd behaviour adding/subtracting small numbers

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, compute-shader

When adding/subtracting numbers around 0.002 in a HLSL compute shader, there is some really odd behaviour.

```cpp
#pragma kernel Fade

RWTexture2D<float4> Result;

[numthreads(8,8,1)]
void Fade (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    Result[id.xy] = Result[id.xy] + 0.001;
}
```

Result is the texture that is displayed, it's initially passed in as black. The idea is to achieve a slow fade to white, which works when I set the number to 0.0023 or above but not when below.

Here's a list of cases which result in different behaviour:

- 0.0022 ends up with a grey which doesn't lighten further
- 0.00221 lights up fine again.
- 0.00219 doesn't light up.

When subtracting from a non-black colour:

- 0.00195 doesn't subtract
- 0.00196 does subtract

Any hints towards this would be appreciated.

Comment: It can be some weird behavior with precision. Checkout https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-DataTypesAndPrecision.html . It would probably be better to pass in a variable with range 0 to 1 into the shader, and then return it directly or multiply it with any texture you have.

Comment: @Pete would that really make a difference? Those docs say that on PC hardware, I'm always going to be using 32-bit floats which should be high precision enough for this operation. Specifically the fact it stops at grey (~0.4) when I add 0.0022 seems to suggest it's not a precision issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer: for some reason Unity was defaulting to a very limited RenderTextureFormat. i have now modified my render texture definition to read

```cs
renderTexture = new RenderTexture(width, height, 32, RenderTextureFormat.ARGBFloat);
```

And now everything works flawlessly.

Comment: Good to see you found a solution, but please do be aware that with this solution the fade speed is probably frame rate dependent.

Comment: @Pete oh yeah, definitely. i tripped down the example quite a lot, in the original the process is way more elaborate, but ultimately i don't want to bother people with trying to comprehend that. hence, the most basic example i could find.